# Top-down vs. Bottom-up database design: Real world examples

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling

Ok, I can find hundreds of references on the internet of the difference between top-down database design vs bottom up database design approaches, however, I can't seeem to find any real world examples, or any inofrmation on which design is really more suitable for what circumstances.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm basing this answer on this [Data Modeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_modeling) Wikipedia article.

About half way down the Wikipedia page, there's a section called "Modeling methodologies".

A top down approach is used to create a new database.  You model the objects at a logical level, then you apply the objects to a physical database design.  For example, a relational database would need the objects to be mapped to tables.

To use a real world example, a payroll system would have to have person objects, along with other objects that hold pay rules (overtime for over 40 hours a week, overtime for more than 10 hours a day, etc.).  There would be a pay period object, which holds the dates of the pay period and the pay day.  This description isn't a complete design.  As you think about the application more, you come up with additional objects that need to exist, and additional entities that need to be part of existing objects.

A bottom up approach is used to migrate a database from one physical database to another.  Migrating from Oracle to IBM's DB2 usually requires some changes, as the column data types are not completely compatible.  You would create tables based on the existing tables.  Sometimes, you try to make a near exact copy, to minimize the application coding changes.  Other times, you alter the table structure, usually to normalize further or to group columns together in a more logical way.  Yes, the application code would have to change to accommodate the new database schema.  But sometimes, the pain is worth the gain.

I've seen lots of database migrations.  They're hard to describe in a post.  They are painful to work through.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the differences between these approaches, let's consider some jobs that are bottom-up in nature.  In statistical analysis, analysts are taught to take a sample from a small population and then infer the results to the overall population.  Physicians are also trained in the bottom-up approach.  Doctors examine specific symptoms and then infer the general disease that causes the symptoms.

An example of jobs that require the top-down approach include project management and engineering tasks where the overall requirements must be specified before the detail can be understood.  For example, an automobile manufacturer must follow a top-down approach to meet the overall specifications for the car.  If a car has the requirement that it cost less than 15,000 dollars, gets 25 miles per gallon, and seating five people.   In order to meet these requirements the designers must start by creating a specification document and then drilling down to meet these requirements.

taken from http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_object_top_down_bottom_up.htm